# Rvalue and forwarding references to C-style arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

Playing with rvalue- and forwarding references to C-style arrays, I stumbled upon weird behaviour. At first I thought it was due to my lack of understanding how C-style arrays bind to `&&` references, but now, after reading this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508703/temporary-const-array-not-binding-to-rvalue-reference), it seems to be an MS C++ compiler bug.

The code:

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility> 

template<typename T>
void foo(T&&) {
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<T>() << '\n';
}

void bar(int(&)[2]) {
    std::cout << "int(&)[2]\n";
}

void bar(int(&&)[2]) {
    std::cout << "int(&&)[2]\n";
}

int main() {
    int arr[2];
                         //          MSVS 2018 / gcc 7.1.0 & clang 5.0.0
    foo(arr);            // Outputs: int(&)[2] / int(&)[2]
    foo(std::move(arr)); // Outputs: int(&)[2] / int[2]

    bar(arr);            // Outputs: int(&)[2] / int(&)[2]
    bar(std::move(arr)); // Outputs: int(&)[2] / int(&&)[2]

    return 0;
}
```

Are gcc/clang right here? Can this be classified as an MS compiler bug?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/203305/rvalue-reference-to-array-can-bind-to-lvalue-refer.html

Comment: @Barry, thank you. `int[2]` seems to be indeed the most natural choice.